# How to append parts to an inline script URL using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, append

I have a script (Google Maps, to be exact) that is loading dynamically, and for a couple of reasons, I cannot alter how this initially loads by default.

Through JavaScript, I would like to find the string `libraries=places` and change it to `libraries=places,visualization` after the fact

So, the originally output:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places">
</script>
```

Would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,visualization">
</script>
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: By the time any Javascript runs that could change the `src`, the script with the original URL will already have been loaded.

Comment: can you use the maps API to add the library post-boot?

Answer (score 0):

this solution should apply to yours as well: 
[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

`script.src = url;` will be the line where you add the src url however you like

Comment: This requires him to change the original HTML to remove the `<script>` tag, but he says he can't do that. If he could, he could just change the URL to the one he wants.

Answer (score -1):

First of all Give the google map script tag an ID:

```
<script id="google_map_script" type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

Then do:

```
var google_map_script = document.getElementById("google_map_script")
google_map_script.setAttribute("src", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,visualization")
```

Edit: since apparently this isn't what is needed then what about this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');

my_awesome_script.setAttribute('src','https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,visualization');

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Also have a look into using [postscribe](https://github.com/krux/postscribe).

Comment: wouldn't that load the un-changed tag url first, then load the 2nd one (if it did anything)?

Comment: @dandavis I don't think you can do any better. Javascript can't alter anything until it has been loaded into the DOM, and loading a `<script>` tag into the DOM executes the script.

Comment: @Barmar: i didn't see the part about not changing the script tag. to be 100% accurate, you can use `document.write("<style>")` to "comment-out" anything before the next "</style>", which can snuff yet-unseen scripts, but there's likely an easier way, and if he's "going in" after the tag, it's too late.